# How can I simplify maven commands?

Tags: maven, maven-3

Can I simplify command by combining some of them?

So, for example instead of typing the command `mvn verify -D skipTests -P !fed-build && mvn -P cargo.run` I could run something like `mvn -P quickBuild`

**Background**

I am working in a multiskilled team and in other to improve efficiency we have created profiles to work faster.

So, for example, a back-end developer usually runs the following command:

```
mvn verify -D skipTests -P !fed-build && mvn -P cargo.run
```

A front end developer runs

```
mvn -P fed-build && mvn -Pcargo.run
```

And both might run a full build when updating or creating a new branch

```
mvn clean verify && mvn -Pcargo.run
```

mvn verify -D skipTests -P !fed-build && mvn -P cargo.run

From time to time these commands change slightly depending on the needs or on the project so I would like to have a way to unify all these commands so developers don't have to remember/type those long commands and can abstract from the project they are working.

Comment: The short answer is no. But there are a few things about your example commands that I don't understand. 1. Why do you once deactivate `fed-build` and once activate it? Either it is automatically active or not. Furthermore, if you always need the content of `cargo.run`, why not put it into the build itself?

Comment: @JFMeier Thank you for answering the question. I need to keep the ´fed-build´ in and the ´cargo.run´ out so it doesn't affect the full lifecycle of the application. So when we want to build the artefact for release it builds the front end assets but it doesn't try to run the application in a Tomcat instance.

Comment: 1. Is fed-build activated or deactivated by default? 2. Why do you use a second Maven run for `cargo.run` instead of using it in first Maven run?

Comment: 1. Activated by default but most of our running commands deactivate it. 2. I never thought about that, We were instructed to do 2 commands, so I assumed that they were required as separate steps. It might depend on the phase of the lifecycle where cargo.run is invoked. I will verify this.